# Macbook Pro TrackPad not clicking

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

I'm using a macbook pro, now the TrackPad could not be "clicked" when I press the bottom right corner.

I couldn't do the "right click" now.

This is awkward.

I know that in System Preference -> TrackPad, I could set the "Tap to click", but then I couldn't use the three fingers swipe to toggle different screens.

Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWklKH8Pu_w) recommends resetting the SMC:

Here is how to do that for most Apple computers:

1. Turn off your computer.
2. Press Shift-Option-Control, on the left side of the keyboard, and the power button, at the same time and hold it for 10 seconds.
3. Let go of all the buttons.
4. Turn your computer back on with the power button.

The instructions might be different for your Mac model. (E.g. if you have a Mac with Apple silicon and not an Intel processor, or if your Mac has the *Apple T2 Security Chip*, or is an older one with a removable battery).
Check this [Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295) to see which instructions apply to your computer (and for more information on the SMC reset).

Comment: This worked great. For some reason, I was unable to physically touch-down and feel the 'click`, but after doing the above, everything returned to normal.

Comment: Not quite sure of the logic as to why this works (thought it was a hardware fail), but it did work for me too! Thanks so much

Comment: Mine was not even clicking physically, after this it started Amazing!.

Comment: Fixed my problem too, thank you (upvoted). So why does this make a difference. I'm intrigued as to why its clicking now and wasn't before. It seemed more a mechanical problem.

Comment: @markc For those of you wondering about this fix, if you're using a newer (2015 or later) macbook pro, and this restored the physical click for you, it's probably because your trackpad "clicks" using a haptic feedback system like the newer iPhone home buttons and it's not really clicking at all, it's all some clever trickery to make it feel like it's clicking. If this worked for you, you should find that if you power off your computer completely, it will stop "clicking". This SMC reset probably fixes something wrong in the software controlling the haptic engine.

Comment: @moneyt  - thank you, I tested this and you're right :-) I didn't even notice that, it really feels like a "click" and mechanical very interesting: http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/133176-what-is-force-touch-apple-s-haptic-feedback-technology-explained

Comment: perfect, worked as described

Comment: Thank you so much for delaying my regret that my $2k laptop was wasted!

Comment: SMC didn't fix trackpad...I am still unable to click

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes its just your magic mouse is sitting somewhere, maybe in your bag and triggering a click. Make sure you turn off the bluetooth.

Comment: It was my cat laying on an outer trackpad! So I wasn't able to click a trackpad on a laptop. Gush.

Comment: Wow, this was it for me! I didn't realize this until I read this comment. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Multiple time got the problem, this always was the case! And it's so hard to find out. Force restart couple times in vain. Google is the rescue.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your macbook pro model you should see a small screw on it inside the computer. Just do 1/4 turn left or right to adjust click on the trackpad

Comment: It is also worth noting that on most models, if the battery has began swelling, it can prevent clicking.

Comment: @TGYK: I've heard about the battery-swelling thing too, but I haven't been able to find a good source that verifies that it is a real problem and/or what to do about it. I'm also wondering how the temperature of the computer or the ambient-air affects swelling. I experience the trackpad-clicking issue intermittently, but I'm on my second battery. It's not clear if/how the new battery affected the issue.

Comment: @nizx: Your solution sounds intriguing. It would be helpful to see a photo (or other details) that illustrates exactly how to access and locate the screw that can be adjusted.

Comment: @EJMak I have no image, but I will try to explain what I presume he is referring to. In my case, I have a 5,5 MBP (2009), and the trackpad, revealed lifting the battery, has one big screw in direction of the front of the computer. It has a tri-wing screwdrive (no a cruciform, it looks more like the Mercedes-Star), so I need a special Bit to move it.

Answer (score 2):

Putting in a new battery fixed my trackpad! I don't understand how, maybe my mouse was tired... But it clicks great now, yay!

Comment: In some models the trackpad doesn't work properly if the battery has swelled as the swelling interferes with the trackpad. A new battery fixes this as it's not in a swollen state.

Comment: I just worked on a macbook of a friend of mine and the track pad had erupted at least 1cm above where it should have been at the back --opposite the keyboard.  The battery had swollen to about twice the usual thickness!  After that, I noticed that on my own macbook pro, the left click is getting really hard to push, so I'm ordering a new battery.

Comment: I had this same issue and noticed that the right of my unibody MBP's trackpad was slightly bulging. On taking off the back cover, it was immediately apparent that the battery was swollen (in the region below the right side of the trackpad).
Replacing the battery solved the issue and the trackpad now clicks perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Magic Mouse connected in the laptop bag! Make sure to check bluetooth connections!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried four/three fingers and/or two finger tap/click?

Settings have an option to change between four/three fingers for swiping between full screen apps and has a two finger tap or click option too.

In my opinion Macbook pros have a large right click corners. too large for me and can accidently click with the palm of my hand.

Answer (score 0):

Bend your trackpad from the opposite side of your mac, and you will find the clicking works again.( and fail again in several minutes)

Answer (score 0):

Magic Trackpad here covered by a book... "But laptop trackpad was clicking earlier today." Yes it was - until I turned on bluetooth in order to connect the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I simply rebooted and it began working again. That might be the simplest solution in a lot of cases..